# django-viewflow - getting task URL without request

Tags: django-viewflow

Knowing `task` instance is there a way to get the `url` of it? For example in the cookbook: https://github.com/viewflow/cookbook/blob/master/helloworld/demo/helloworld/flows.py - how do I get the url of `assign` task of `approve` `flow_task`?

I know there is `flow_task.get_task_url(task, url_type='guess', namespace='', **kwargs)`, but the point is that from what I can see the `namespace` is usually fetched from `self.request.resolver_match.namespace`. That's not ideal - what if we are in other part of the app and we simply want to provide links to the tasks directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as with django reverse you need to pass a namespace to get an URL. In case of build-in viewflow frontend the namespace is `viewflow:[app_label]:[flow_label]` ex: "viewflow:helloworld:helloworld"

Comment: Yes, I see. It would be worthwhile to simply add `get_absolute_url` to Task model though.

Comment: It's not possible, since namespace mapping could be different depends on end user url config.

Comment: I suppose you are right, but it should still be better to have global SETTINGS variable for viewflow namespace and use that in `get_absolute_url`, rather than this kind of complicated view of getting the url. By default it should use `get_absolute_url`, if an end user wants to modify default behaviour, he can set the settings variable to let the framework know about it...

Comment: I don't think that adding more settings could solve any problem. Explicit namespace passing is match better.

Comment: I am trying to reverse the url but I got `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'urls'`, coming from `base_url, self.viewset.urls, module=self)`, and `self.viewset` is a string value `'viewflow.frontend.viewset.FrontendViewSet'`

Answer (score 0):

To get the url of a task all you need is the `app_name(app_namespace), flow_namespace and flow_label`.
The most challenging item here is the flow_namespace (if you have not used the frontend urls).
To resolve this, you could use a map borrowing from FlowListMixin's ns_map. Defining the flow_namespace for every flow in your project. 
You then determine the flows namespace and url_name from the above.

```py
ns_map = {'MyFlow':'flow_namespace', 'AnotherFlow':'flow_namespace2'}

# flow_namespace as defined in the urls.py
# e.g if you defined your flow urls as
# flow_urls = FlowViewSet(MyFlow).urls
# flow_urls2 = FLowViewSet(MyFlow2).urls
# urlpatterns = [url(r'flow_path/', include(flow_urls, name=flow_namespace)),
# url(r'flow_path2/', include(flow_urls2, name=flow_namespace2)),
# ]
# With this is included in the root_url as
# urlpatterns = [
#     url(r'app/' include(app_urls, namespace='app_namespace')
#]
```

What you need is to reverse the flow like this
reverse('app_name:flow_namespace:flow_label', kwargs={'process_pk':ppk, 'task_pk':tpk})

```py
flow_class_name = task.process.flow_class.__name__
flow_namespace = ns_map.get(flow_class_name)
app_name = task.process.flow_class.__module__.split('.')[0]
flow_label = task.flow_task.name
url_name = "{}:{}:{}".format(app_name, flow_label, url_name)
```

Then you can reverse your task url

```py
url = reverse(url_name, kwargs={"task_pk", task.pk, "process_pk":task.flow_process.pk}

# If you know where you are you could use resolver match to determine
# the app namespace. Be Sure of this, see more of that [here][1]
```

**NOTE: I am assuming that you namespaced your apps as app_name
If it is different you have to find alternatives to finding the app_names namespace but that should not be too difficult.**

Comment: It does not help to give a negative score without a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the task object in a template, you can extract the url as follows:

```
<a href="/workflow/formworkflow/{{ task.process.flow_class.flow_name }}/{{ task.process.flow_class.process_name }}/{{ task.process.pk }}/{{task.flow_task.name}}/{{task.id}}">Task Link</a>
```

This could be added as a template filter if used often.

This is a dirty hack untill I understand how the namespaces work.